# Saving the value of radio buttons on click using ajax

Tags: java, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Im creating a exam using php.

My problem is when the page is refresh the checked in the radio button dissappear.. i using ajax to save it in database everytime the radio button is click

```
<?php
session_start();
include './connect.php';
?>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="online"></div>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM questions");
$count = mysql_num_rows($result);
while($rows = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
function saveans(){

var aa = $('input:radio[name=a1]:checked').val();
alert(aa);
 $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url:  "ans.php",
      data: "stdID=1&q=2&ans="+aa,
     })



}

</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#online").load("./tmr.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   //alert("aa");
      $("#online").load('./tmr.php');
      $.ajax({
                       type: "POST",
                       url: "./update.php",
                       data: "stdID=1"
     })
   }, 1000);
   $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
});

</script>


<p><?php echo $rows["questions"]; ?></p>
<input type="radio" id="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" name="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" value="A" onClick="saveans(this);"/>A. <?php echo $rows['choi1']; ?><br/>
<input type="radio" id="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" name="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" value="B" onClick="saveans(this);"/>B. <?php echo $rows['choi2']; ?><br/>
<input type="radio" id="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" name="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" value="C" onClick="saveans(this);"/>C. <?php echo $rows['choi3']; ?><br/>
<input type="radio" id="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" name="a<?php echo $rows['questionNum']; ?>" value="D" onClick="saveans(this);"/>D. <?php echo $rows['choi4']; ?><br/>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>

and the php code is

<?php
include './connect.php';$command = mysql_query("UPDATE ans_1 SET ans".$_POST['q']."='".$_POST['ans']."' WHERE std_id='".$_POST['stdID']."'") or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

the problem is i what to change the  data: "stdID=1&q=2&ans="+aa.. the name of my radio button is a1,a2,a3 for multiple radio buttons.. i want to save it on my database depends the name
Is it possible to insert database value in a ajax variable?
and the std value is come from session

Answer (score 1):

You define your function as :

```
function saveans(){
                 ^---no arguments
```

But invoke it in your onclick handers as:

```
onClick="saveans(this);"
                 ^^^^---passing in "this"
```

You want:

```
function saveans(obj) {
    answer = obj.value;
    ... do ajax ...
}
```

There's no need to look up by ID (and a hard-coded id at that), since `this` and `obj` will already be the exact same DOM element you're trying to look up by ID anyways.

Comment: theres nothing wrong in my code i just have to add obj? and what about the data?

Comment: im getting the value of different radio buttons but still it is save at only 1 field i want it save in different fields depending on what is the radio buttons name for example the radio button name is a1 it will automatically store at my field at a1 and soon